# I'm having trouble storing the value in R0 into the correct memory location (LC-3 Assembly)

Tags: assembly

Here is my LC-3 Assembly code.
It is designed to add up the 10 values in x3100 through x3109 and store them in x310A.
It correctly adds the values, storing the total in R0, however I cannot seem to get it to properly store that value in x310A.

```
.ORIG x3000

        AND R0, R0, #0        ; use R0 to store total (start at zero)
        LD R1, ten           ; put number of iterations in R1
        LD R2, addr          ; R2 stores the number we're looking at
loop    LDR R3, R2, #0        ; load current number
        ADD R0, R0, R3        ; add current number to R0
        ADD R2, R2, #1        ; set R2 to the next address
        ADD R1, R1, #-1       ; subtract from loop counter
        BRp loop             ; loop while still positive

        ST R0, sum           ; store total
        HALT

ten     .FILL #10             ; number of iterations
addr    .FILL x3100           ; starting address
sum     .BLKW 1              ; space for total

.END
```

Comment: I don't think that debugging your assembly code is on-topic here.  Any community votes?  (via vote to close)

Comment: From tag `assembly`'s wiki: *off-topic here. Do not ask questions about how to write code in assembly. However, conceptual questions about how coding in assembly is different may be appropriate.* - my take: different from coding in high level languages and designing code (algorithms?) in pseudocode. (The problem is in the directives, not in the code/instructions/addresses.)